# Joining tables in dynamic entity collector with Symfony 2.8 framework

Tags: symfony, doctrine, query-builder

I get an Product array back in this case. The products are linked to Categories. The Categories do not have their own array, but are put next to those of products.

The framework is use is Symfony 2.8

#### Current output

```
   array(1) {
      [0]=>
      array(3) {
        [0]=>
        array(26) {
          ["id"]=>
          int(902)
          ["articleNumber"]=>
          string(8) "32132435"
          ["name"]=>
          string(31) "Sensa Umbria 105 LTD 2017 Heren"
        }
        ["id"]=>
        int(18)
        ["name"]=>
        string(12) "Aanbiedingen"
      }
    }
```

#### Wanted output

```
  array(1) {
      [0]=>
      array(3) {
        [0]=>
        array(26) {
          ["id"]=>
          int(902)
          ["articleNumber"]=>
          string(8) "32132435"
          ["name"]=>
          string(31) "Sensa Umbria 105 LTD 2017 Heren"
          ["category"]=> array(2) {
              ["id"]=>
              int(18)
              ["name"]=>
              string(12) "Aanbiedingen"
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

#### The current function

```
private $allowedEntities = [
    'product' => 'CasProductBundle:Product',
    'project' => 'CasProjectBundle:Project',
];

private $activeFields = [
    'active',
    'isActive'
];

private $delFields = [
    'deleted',
    'isDeleted'
];

public function getEntityAction()
{
    $defaults = [
        'showNonActive' => true,
        'showDeleted' => false
    ];

    $params = array_merge($defaults, $_POST);

    if (!isset($params['entity']))
        throw new NotFoundHttpException('No entity given');

    if (!array_key_exists($params['entity'], $this->allowedEntities))
        throw new NotFoundHttpException('Entity is not allowed');

    $entityShortName = $this->allowedEntities[$params['entity']];
    $entityShortNameArr = explode(":", $entityShortName);
    $bundle = $this->get('kernel')->getBundle($entityShortNameArr[0], true);
    $entityNamespace = $bundle->getNamespace() . '\Entity\\' . $entityShortNameArr[1];

    $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository($this->allowedEntities[$params['entity']]);

    /** @var QueryBuilder $qb */
    $qb = $repository->createQueryBuilder('p');

    if (isset($params['fields'])) {
        $temp = ''; $i = 0;
        foreach ($params['fields'] as $field) {
            $temp .= ($i != 0 ? ', ' : '') . 'p.' . $field;
            $i++;
        }
        $qb->select($temp);
    }

    if (isset($params['join'])) {
        foreach ($params['join'] as $table => $fields) {
            $temp = ''; $i = 0;
            foreach ($fields as $field) {
                $temp .= ($i != 0 ? ', ' : '') . strtolower($table) . '.' . $field;
                $i++;
            }
            $qb->addSelect($temp);
            $qb->innerJoin('p.' . $table, strtolower($table));
        }
    }

    $i = 0;
    if (!$params['showDeleted']) {
        foreach ($this->delFields as $field) {
            if (property_exists($entityNamespace, $field)) {
                $qb->{($i == 0 ? 'where' : 'andWhere')}('p.' . $field . ' = 0');
                $i++; break;
            }
        }
    }

    if (!$params['showNonActive']) {
        foreach ($this->activeFields as $field) {
            if (property_exists($entityNamespace, $field)) {
                $qb->{($i == 0 ? 'where' : 'andWhere')}('p.' . $field . ' = 1');
                $i++; break;
            }
        }
    }

    if (isset($params['filters'])) {
        foreach ($params['filters'] as $key => $filter) {
            $qb
                ->andWhere('p.' . $key . (is_array($filter) ? ' IN (:filter)' : ' = :filter'))
                ->setParameter('filter', $filter);
        }
    }

    if (isset($params['sort'])) {
        $i = 0;
        foreach ($params['sort'] as $field => $sort) {
            $qb
                ->{($i == 0 ? 'orderBy' : 'addOrderBy')}('p.' . $field, $sort);
            $i++;
        }
    }

    if (isset($params['limit'])) {
        $qb->setMaxResults($params['limit']);
    }

    if (isset($params['offset'])) {
        $qb->setFirstResult($params['offset']);
    }

    $entities = $qb
        ->getQuery()
        ->getArrayResult()
    ;

    return new JsonResponse($entities);
}
```

#### These are all the parameters I can pass to the function.

```
- entity =>
    "product"

- showNonActive => (default: false)
    true

- showDeleted => (default: false)
    true

- limit =>
    5

- offset =>
    10

- filters =>
    'id' => 28
    or
    'id' => [7, 8, 9]

- sort =>
    ['id' => 'ASC', 'createDate' => 'DESC']

- fields =>
    ['id', 'name', 'createDate']

- join =>
    [
       'categories' => ['id', 'name']
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query building seems a bit complicated, but could you try using `partial` selects from doctrine.

Simplified version could look like this:

`$qb->select('partial p.{id, articleNumber, name}')
    ->addSelect('partial c.{id, name}')
    ->from('...:Product', 'p')
    ->innerJoin('p.category', 'c');`

Add where clauses, sorting and etc. and get result the same way:

`$entities = $qb
        ->getQuery()
        ->getArrayResult()
    ;`

Keep in mind this might have some side effects: [link](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/partial-objects.html).